# Publishing does not update published state but items get published

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1-hr1

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 while publishing a large number of Pages (more then 100) few Pages appear as success in Publishing Queue, after that all other Pages remain stuck on "Ready For Transport" state.

We checked on delivery side all Pages got published successfully but inside Publishing Queue the state of Pages does not update. After restarting Publisher Service, publish state gets updated to Success for all Pages.

There is no error on CMS server inside event viewer and Publisher log file. We have already applied all hotfixes.No of threads for rendering and deploying are 4 on CMS server

Deployer service is installed as standalone java application on a different server.

From the log we have find out that after some time there is no Transport service response captured

Comment: I think it is useful if you **edit** your question and provide a bit more details on your CM and Publisher setup, like is it outscaled or tuned with specific parameters for number of render/deploy threads etc.

Comment: Can you confirm you've set the logs to WARN or DEBUG too? and that you're checking the logs on the CM Publisher server(s) **and** on the Deployer(s). The publisher should contain entries such as "DestinationController - All Deployer endpoints have completed" and/or "setting transaction to completed" with the correct transaction ID. And the HTTP Upload website's log should have the "TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package" along with clean-up references - is this OK (are the files being locked before being cleaned up and then cleaned up on a reboot)